# program crash in accessing struct elements

Tags: c++, struct

struct `a` has `int b`, and pointer to struct as its elements. And program crashes without printing results.

```
struct a{
    int b{5};
    a* next=new a;
    a(){
        next->b=3;
    }
    
};
int main(){
    a a1;
    cout<<a1.b<<endl;
    cout<<(*(a1.next)).b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected output to be:

> 5
>
> 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a* next=new a;
```

Your `a` struct has a member called `next`, which gets default-initialized by `new`. Every instance of `a` that your program creates will have a class member called `next`, which gets initialized by `new`. That's how classes and default class member initializers work.

This member is, like I said, is another struct `a`. Which, of course, also has a member called `next` which will be initialized by `new`. Just like every instance of struct `a`, of course.

And the second `struct a` will also have a `next` member, like all `a`s do, which will get initialized by `new`. This third instance of `a` will have it's own `next`, which will get initialized by `new`.

And so on, in perpetuity, until your computer runs out of memory, creating an infinite chain of struct `a`s.

It is not clear what your intent is here, but this answers the question of why your program is crashing.